# Unable to access mysql over LAN when there is no internet

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server running locally inside my building, lets say it is on machine 192.168.0.116. Normally, everything works fine. But, my town, and by extension my building, loses internet from time to time. When this happens I am unable to connect to the MySQL server.

I have checked, I can still SSH into 192.168.0.116, so it strikes me that the problem is with the MySQL configuration, not the network.

Why does the server need and outside connection? Is there some type of preference that is making need to call outside to check addresses or something?

Comment: This seems a question for superuser or similar. SO is for programming questions.

Comment: Is your client addressing the server by IP or by url? What kind of program or service are you using to access the MySQL server?

Comment: Access over IP. Have tried direct connection through terminal and also through a desktop app.